# QGIS intersect or summary function not working precise enough?

Tags: intersection, overlapping-features, vector-layer, combine, summary

For my thesis I am trying to convert some data using QGIS.

I have: A vector layer with all the parcels of a municipality as polygons and a layer with all the
buildings in said municipality as 2D polygons with their height as an attribute.

I want: A layer of all the parcels with the built surface and average height as attributes, the exact geometrie of the buildings does not matter for the export.

The challenge: The parcel and building layers are not exactly aligned as they were not made he same way. I reached out to the publishers of this data and they confirmed
there is a margin of error that cannot really be solved.

To work around this I figured I would intersect both layers, which would on many occasions give me a block of like 99.9% of the building and a little "*splinter*" of the building on the parcel next to it. I then added the geometry attributes to these "*building blocks*" and multiplied this with the height to get the volume as an attribute. Then I used the summary (join attributes by location) function to sum the volume and area of all *building blocks* on each parcel. By dividing the summed volume with the summed area I get the average height. This means I have a slight inaccuracy because of the *splinters*, but that is not a problem. So far so good, until I noticed something while using this result:

THE PROBLEM: I noticed that the total built volume of all the parcels combined is significantly larger (about 15%) than the total volume of the original building layer. When looking close I found some weird things happen with the "splinters":

[image]

The parcel outlined in the image above contains 4 building blocks. One of those is of course the big *building block* inside the parcel, with an area of 91.7. There are also 2 small *splinters*. The fourth *building block* however is the one from the parcel above it, area 96.5.

[image]

The fact that the *building block* is added to the wrong parcel is already a problem, however when looking at that top parcel the same thing happens: both *building blocks* are counted and the area is again about 188. This is happening in many places, leading to a lot of *building blocks* being counted twice, hence the inflated total volume.
Note that the *building blocks* have an intersection point with the parcel border (see the picture below).

Why is this and how can I avoid this?

Maybe I should try other software? I'm really lost here.

I will add more details below.

[image]

EXTRA INFO:

In the intersect function I checked the "split parts" box.

In the summary function I checked the "contain", "overlap", "are within" and "equals" box. I did not check the "intersect" box.

*WORKAROUND

I had a shower thought last night, and I managed to avoid using the intersect and summarize function: instead of assigning the buildings to parcels, I worked the other way around. I assigned each parcel an ID-number. Then I used the "combine attributes based on location" function using the "largest overlap" (one-to-one), giving each building an parcel ID. After that I combined the parcels and buildings based on said ID. This created a lot of duplicates for parcels with multiple buildings, so I combined them based on their ID, summing the areas and volumes of the buildings. By dividing the volume with the area I can get the average height per parcel as well.

I checked it and the total volume and area of my resulting layer are exactly the same as the input, so this pretty much solves everything. Some buildings that are built over a parcel line are now only assigned to one parcel but that just reflects reality more.

Comment: Can you provide a minimal example of 5 or so geometries and the steps to reproduce your issue with them?

Comment: If you run a v.clean and a delete duplicate geometries on your intersected result does that fix your problem?  (In the v.clean input line and area, and use break, snap, & bpol with different tolerances, perhaps 1m for the snap to start, and select an output of area.)  Recalculate your areas and other values.

Comment: I think you should cut/paste your workaround from the area reserved for questions into the area reserved for answers.